# Trying to add IIS_IUSRS to Administrators group

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, iis-7.5

When I bring up the AD Groups via Computer->Manage->Local Users and Groups, I can see IIS_IUSRS in the list, so I click on the Properties of the Administrators group, then click Add...select the Location to by my local computer, make sure the Object Types has "Built-in security principals" is checked, and I enter IIS_IUSRS in the object name text box, and it tells me that the IIS_IUSRS object cannot be found.

What am I doing wrong here (besides giving IIS_IUSRS Admin privileges)?

Comment: I'm not a sys admin, but giving admin privilege to the internet access is not a good idea in order to me.

Comment: This question doesn't belong on this website. Flagged.

Comment: SixHouse, why?

Felice, this is only on a Development machine, not for Production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure using the "built-in" account IIS_IUSRS is like a regular group account that you can add to administrators.  For more information on that account, see this:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis/

My guess is you are having permissions issues when running a site in anonomous mode for writing files.  Here are some possible suggestions from the best to worst (IMO):

---

**1: Use impersonation** to do 'elevated' level tasks in code just for that function.  Here is a code sample: (use impersonation class/code below: Impersonation.vb) Example:

```
Using Impersonate As New Impersonation.Impersonate
Using Usr As System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext 
    = Impersonate.ImpersonateUser("<domain username>", "<domain password>", "<domain>")
    'do elevated security level task...

    'System.IO.File.Copy(...)

    Impersonate.UndoImpersonate(Usr)
End Using
```

End Using

---

**2: Create a virtual directory** to do 'elevated' tasks on a specific directory.  In IIS you can set this to no be anonomous and have elevated permission to write files, for example.

---

**3: Do impersonation in web.config**

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />
```

---

---

---Impersonation.vb----

```
Imports System
```

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security.Principal

Namespace Impersonation

```
Public Class Impersonate
    Implements IDisposable

    Private Declare Auto Function LogonUser Lib "advapi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal lpszUsername As String, _
    ByVal lpszDomain As String, _
    ByVal lpszPassword As String, _
    ByVal dwLogonType As Integer, _
    ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, _
    ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Boolean

    Declare Function GetLastError Lib "kernel32" () As Integer

    Public Function ImpersonateUser(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String, ByVal Domain As String) As WindowsImpersonationContext

        Dim tokenHandle As New IntPtr(0)
        Dim dupeTokenHandle As New IntPtr(0)


        Dim mWIC As WindowsImpersonationContext = Nothing

        tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim loggedOn As Boolean = LogonUser(Username, Domain, Password, 8, 0, tokenHandle)

        If loggedOn Then
            Dim mWI As New WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle)
            mWIC = mWI.Impersonate()    'start the impersonation
        End If

        Return mWIC

    End Function

    Public Function UndoImpersonate(ByVal mWIC As WindowsImpersonationContext) As Boolean
        If mWIC IsNot Nothing Then
            mWIC.Undo()
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    Private disposedValue As Boolean = False        ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                ' TODO: free managed resources when explicitly called
            End If

            ' TODO: free shared unmanaged resources
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

End Namespace

Comment: All I'm trying to do is let my website write our error to the server's event log. Instead of it writing the error that I want to see, it's throwing an exception saying there was an error writing to the event log because of permissions. Does that change your answer?

All of our other developers have it setup so that IIS_IUSRS is apart of the Administrators group, but for some reason I can't get mine added...very frustrating.

Comment: No, this does not change the answer.  I use this code exactly for that... writing error to the error log.