# "Object named IIS_IUSRS could not be found" when adding user to PHP sessions directory iis 8

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm running windows server 2012 R2 running IIS 8. New to the whole windows server environment.

To install PHP, I'm following the below tutorial

[Install and Configure PHP](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php)

Part of it says, in order to use PHP's session functionality properly I need to create a new folder "sessions" and add "IIS_IUSRS" to the folder.

However when I enter the same in the "Object files box" it gives me the "Object named IIS_IUSRS was not found" error.

**So far I have referred to the following, but none has been that helpful**

[Trying to add IIS_IUSRS to Administrators group [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447265/trying-to-add-iis-iusrs-to-administrators-group)

[IIS or IIS_IUSRS permisions so that PHP can write files for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708084/iis-or-iis-iusrs-permisions-so-that-php-can-write-files-for-wordpress)

[IIS_IUSRS group missing](https://serverfault.com/questions/399288/iis-iusrs-group-missing)

[How to give Folder Permission for IIS User in C#?](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/686065/How-to-give-Folder-Permission-for-IIS-User-in-Csha)

[IIS_IUSRS and IUSR permissions in IIS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8)

Been researching for hours, but can find nothing concrete enough.

Answer (score 21):

I know this is old, but since I came across this when I was searching for a solution, might as well answer it.

Source of my answer: [IIS_IUSRS group is not found in Windows 7 laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061709/iis-iusrs-group-is-not-found-in-windows-7-laptop)

1. In the main page of IIS Manager right click on the web site you would like to configure (Found in connections->[Machinename]->Sites->[Yoursite]);
2. "[Server name] Properties" menu will pop up. Click on the Security tab;
3. Under the "Group or user names:" frame, click the "Edit" button;
4. Click "Add" in the next window;
5. "Select Users, Computers, [...]" pops up; Type "IIS_IUSRS" in "Enter the object names to select";
   6.) Click on "Locations"; **Now scroll up to the top and you should see the name of your  machine you are trying to configure at the top of the tree structure.** Select this entry and hit ok. IIS_IUSRS should now be correctly found for instance as [DMNNAMEOFMACHINE]\IIS_IUSRS;

Comment: Thanks for the help - can't help but think this could've been expressed more clearly and succintly by just saying "make sure you select the machine name in 'From this location' when trying to find 'IIS_IUSRS'" though.

Answer (score 7):

Two things to note when adding `IIS_IUSRS` via the Windows user/group selection dialog shown below:

[image]

1. `IIS_IUSRS` is a group, not a user.  `Groups` is unchecked by default, so you'll need to check it under `Object Types`.
2. `IIS_IUSRS` is not a domain object but is local to the machine.  So, as noted in another answer, ensure the machine name (and not an Active Directory location) is selected under `Locations`.

These parameters can be easy to overlook for those who are accustomed to adding AD users (versus local groups) via this dialog and therefore leaving the default values.