# IIS_IUSRS group is not found in Windows 7 laptop

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7, iis-7.5

I have 500 error when debug an asp.net application on my Windows 7 laptop. It looks like a permission problem.

[image: 1]

Therefore I want to give the permission to the corresponding folder. I tried to add `IIS_IUSRS` to the group. But I can't add it because it doesn't exist. See the image below please.

[image: 2]

**EDIT:**

I checked the user groups. It is there
[image: 3]

Comment: Have you tried adding only IUSRS?

Comment: @RachitGupta, I tried it. It can't be found as well.

Comment: Try this- Click on locations and add your "full computer name"\IUSRS

Comment: @RachitGupta, it still failed. Actually the location already includes the domain. And I can add IIS_IUSRS in my Win 7 desktop.

Comment: I don't think that it is laptop specific problem coz i have done on both. Can you try re-installing IIS? If you can, then try to use Web PI for installation.

Comment: Open computer management console using Start->Run->compmgmt.msc.  Expand Local Users and Groups. Check if group present there. If yes then you need to change "From this location" in screenshot in question.

Comment: @PankajKapare, I updated the question. Yes, it is there. "From this location" I set the location on the root. It is `corporate.xxx.com`.

Comment: Nope. It should be your computer name. This group is local group and doesn't exists on active directory.

Comment: @PankajKapare. It works, I can add `IIS_IUSRS` to my laptop now. But I tried to add `IUSRS`  it just failed. Anyway it works now. Thanks for help. If you would like, please convert your comment to the answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

IIS_USRS is local group added with IIS 7 release. It isn't available on active directory so while searching it location should be selected as local machine name in "From this location" field. You should be able to find "IIS_USRS" group under your local machine.

Comment: I would like to note that the your local computer will be listed at the very top when you click "Locations..."